# Storing huge randomized list of similar items in Redis

Tags: redis, data-storage, high-load

Redis 2.0.3

I need to store a huge list of items in Redis. Each item is a short string (less than 256 characters).

I need to do two operations on the list:

- Add many (several thousands to a million) identical items. (Several times a day)
- Remove one random item from the list. It is not necessary to have "fair" random. Any "good enough" approach will do. (Up to several hundred times a second)

I do not have enough RAM to store all items in a list one by one.

I think that I need to store items in batches, name and a counter. (There will be up to several thousands distinct items, more like several hundreds.)

But I'm not sure how to organize this effectively.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since nobody is up to help me, here is a "dumb" solution, in pseudocode.

1. Get random element:

   ```
   function maybe_get_next_item()
     item_name = SRANDMEMBER "items-set"
     item_key = "items:" + item_name

     new_item_count = DECR (item_key)

     if new_item_count < 0 then
       LOCK -- As explained in SETNX docs
         new_item_count = GET (item_key) -- More added while we were locking?
         if new_item_count and new_item_count < 0 then
           SREM (item_name) -- No, expire it
         end
       UNLOCK
     end

     if new_item_count and new_item_count >= 0 then
       return item_name
     end

     return false -- this item not found
   end

   function get_next_item()
     item_name = maybe_get_next_item()
     while not item_name and (SCARD "items-set" > 0) do
       item_name = maybe_get_next_item()
     end
     return item_name -- false if all items are expended
   end
   ```
2. Insert new elements

   ```
   function insert_items(item_name, amount)
     LOCK -- As explained in SETNX docs
       SADD "items-set" (item_name)
       INCRBY ("items:" + item_name) amount
     UNLOCK
   end
   ```

Please do suggest a better solution if it exists, I'm still groking Redis, and may miss something obvious.

I suspect that `LOCK`/`UNLOCK` in `insert_items()` may be superfluous and can be replaced with `MULTI`/`EXEC`, but I think that it is needed for `LOCK`/`UNLOCK` in `maybe_get_next_item()` to work properly (which I do not know how to replace with `MULTI`/`EXEC`)...

Comment: Note that probabilities here are skewed, as number of identical items does not play any part in the chance to get the item. This is okay for my particular use-case.

Comment: On 2.2 better approach would be to use WATCH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118807/redis-how-to-atomically-remove-an-item-from-set-if-a-counter-in-another-key-is-b