# Atomically remove an item from set if a counter in another key is below zero?

Tags: redis

Redis 2.0.3

In my Redis DB I have a set of items. Each item has a counter, associated with it:

```
MULTI
    SADD "items-set" "foo"
    INCRBY "items:foo" 10000
EXEC
```

New items are added to the set at random intervals.

When user does a certain action, counter is decremented:

```
new_counter = DECR "items:foo"
```

I need to atomically remove the item from the set, when the counter drops below zero (alternatively: when the counter reaches zero exactly, I can fix up logic for that.)

```
if new_counter < 0 then
    MULTI
        SREM "items-set" "foo"
        DEL "items:foo"
    EXEC
end
```

How can I do this without locking by the item name with `SETNX`/`GETSET`?

Solutions, involving change of the way I store data in Redis, are acceptable. (But, just in case, I reserve a right to counter them with some task-specific detail that I could miss in initial text.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just use the new WATCH capability of Redis 2.2:

```
WATCH items-set items:foo
count = GET items:foo
IF count == 0:
    MULTI
    SREM items-set foo
    SET items:foo count-1
    EXEC
ELSE:
    MULTI
    SET items:foo count-1
    EXEC
```

To understand the example you need to understand how WATCH works. Please check the doc at http://redis.io site.

p.s. there are no ways to do this with Redis 2.0.3

Comment: Ah, I wish my client library (sidereal) supported 2.2... Perhaps it is time to switch to another one.

Comment: This requires every client to issue the WATCH and MULTI/EXEC for every operation that needs to conditionally trigger additional commands. The least common case causes overhead for the most common case. 

With Lua scripting in Redis 2.6, could it be a consideration to allow for a persistent WATCH to be registered, where a script or block of script will execute in response to the event? Basically, allowing an arbitrary callback function to be registered as an event listener for a key or set of keys. Can that be efficient?

Answer (score 2):

It should be on a loop, so you can retry if someone else touched the value in the middle.

```
success = false
while not success 
    WATCH items-set items:foo
    count = GET items:foo
    MULTI
    IF count == 0:
        SREM items-set foo
    SET items:foo count-1
    success = EXEC
```